# How to navigate back to previous tab in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In my app there are five tabs, each has there owned back buttons. I want to navigate back to the previous tab on the click of back button, without knowing that from which tab it has navigated.

Here is my code:

```
goBackPreviousTab = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
}
```

Right now it doesn't work for tabs but it works fine for normal navigations. What can I try?

Comment: Please provide your navigation setup and the version you use

Comment: Please provide the code example of how you are calling the goBackPreviousTab function too

Comment: This can be closed as Needs Focus or Needs Details or Needs [MCVE]. It appeared to have been abandoned.